# ORACLE PLSQL Function/Trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql, triggers

I'm trying to create a FUNCTION/TRIGGER that can update the `status_comunal_waste` in table `supply` without the need of writing a query.

EDIT:

```
TRAFFIC (date),(input_quant),(output_quant),(status)
SUPPLY (input_quant), (output_quant),(status_comunal_waste)
```

After I import the DATE, INPUT, OUTPUT, STATUS data into the table TRAFFIC,
with the trigger AIR the data is also imported into the table SUPPLY, with the execption of columns USER_CHANGES, DATE_CHANGES, USER_DELETE, DATE_DELETE as to mimic the changes the  "user" has made if the "user" decides to change or add the data.

So far I've tried something like this

```
create or replace TRIGGER supply_after_insert
after INSERT
ON traffic
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE

Status_comunal_waste VARCHAR2(20);

BEGIN

SELECT SUM(input_quant) - SUM(output_quant)
into Status_comunal_waste
  FROM traffic
  WHERE (key_num_code =200101);

INSERT INTO supply
(Status_comunal_waste) VALUES (Status_comunal_waste);
 END;
```

EDIT:

Meanwhile I switched from creating a trigger to function, and this is written so far:

```
create or replace 
FUNCTION   stat_comunal_waste (key_num_code number)

return number 

is

status_comunal_waste NUMBER;

BEGIN
if (key_num_code = 200101) THEN

SELECT SUM (input_quant) -  SUM (output_quant)
into status_comunal_waste
  FROM traffic
  WHERE key_num_code =200101;
  end if;

  return status_comunal_waste;
 END;
```

The function compiled with no errors but now I get errors with the PACKAGE

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Paket
IS
function stat_comunal_waste (key_num_code number)
return status_comunal_waste;
end Paket;
/
```

Error(3,1): PL/SQL: Declaration ignored

Error(4,8): PLS-00488: 'status_comunal_waste' must be a type

Comment: What does 'with no luck' mean - do you get compilation errors, runtime errors, not the result you expected?Why are you inserting into `status` when you said the table was called `supply`, and you haven't shown any table with a columns called `Status_comunal_waste`. You said you wanted to update something, but you're doing an insert. It's really not very clear what's going on, or why.

Comment: My apologies, I wrote an incorrect statement and incorrect column names (ones I used before). I will edit it. it **does** insert into `supply`, as you've said. The trigger compiled, but it does not do what I thought it would : I manually tried to change one info in the column but it won't show me the changes in the `Supply (status_comunal_waste)` table.

Three columns exist in the Supply table and all of them need to be updated, 1 of them being `status_comunal_waste` column, so I tried to make 1 trigger for each. I switched from triggers to creating functions , I will edit my post now.

Comment: The PLS-00488 is just because your have `return status_comunal_waste` instead of `return number`, as the message indicates really. But that seems to be a side issue. I don't understand why you said you have separate triggers, or why you talk about updating (three values) but show an *insert* that only sets one value. Maybe showing some existing data, what you're inserting, and what you want the data to look like afterwards would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query might be wrong.

```
SELECT SUM(input_quant) - SUM(output_quant) into Status_comunal_waste   
FROM traffic   WHERE key_num_code =200101);
```

Make sure you are getting the correct values. Try to replace the above query with code below and give it a try

```
select SUM(input_quant) into input_q FROM traffic WHERE key_num_code =200101;
select SUM(output_quant) into output_q FROM traffic WHERE key_num_code =200101;
diff := input_q  - output_q;
```

Final insert will be like:

```
INSERT INTO status (Status_comunal_waste) VALUES (diff);
```